# Specifying Swagger response type

Tags: json, web-services, scala, playframework, swagger

I have the following controller method exposed as a REST service with Play Framework. I am using Swagger to generate a description of the service.

```
@ApiOperation(
nickname = "..",
value = "..",
response = classOf[???], 
httpMethod = "GET")
def dateBasedCampaignsSummaryReport(
  profileId: Int,
  start: Int,
  size: Int,
  filterZeroSent: Boolean = false) = {

  import JsonConverters.dateBasedAutomationSummaryWrites

  automationService
    .dateBasedCampaignsSummaryReport(profileId, start, size, filterZeroSent)
    .map { res => Ok(Json.toJson(res)) }
}
```

This method transforms an object of type `DateBasedAutomationSummary`, that is returned by `automationService`, into a json using an implicit `Write`:

```
implicit def dateBasedAutomationSummaryWrites: Writes[DateBasedAutomationSummary] =
(
  (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'dateTime).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'isInProgress).write[Boolean])(as =>
    (
      as.name,
      dateTime2String(as.scheduledDateTime, "d MMM YYYY 'at' HH:mm"),       
      as.isInProgress))
```

Swagger asks me for a type to use with the `response` attribute. Because I use a `Write` object to create my json, the structure of my original type (`DateBasedAutomationSummary`) gets changed and I can not use it. I would like to use the tuple that I am using inside the `dateBasedAutomationSummaryWrites` method . Or something similar. Is there a way to do this?

Note

1. `DateBasedAutomationSummary` is a simple class and the json structure is similar. I do have other classes that are more complex and get changed far more.
2. I would not like to create a new layer of view model classes for all json representations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can register custom converters for your types - take a look here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models#excluding-fields-with-a-custom-model-converter-131-and-greater.

You *may* be able to use the `Write` for the custom converter as well, otherwise you'd have to add the business logic explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, @webron. This is useful, but it would imply duplicating some functionality that i have already written in my Write function. Also it means having to keep it in sync with the newly added Swagger converter.

Comment: If you have your own manipulation process for the output, I'm not sure how you expect it to work otherwise.